# Why the function is being called more number of times inspite of the check?

Tags: jquery

I have a function (An ajax call) , incase of timeout i need to recall the same function 2 times .
So i did this way

So i did this way

```
var number_0f_times_called = 0; // global variable 

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url+'/OMS/oms1/fromscratchmodified?screen_ids=' + screen_ids,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 5000,
    jsonp: false,
    success: function(response) {


    },
    error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            number_0f_times_called =  1;
            recall();
        }
    }
});

function recall()
{
   if(number_0f_times_called<=2)
   {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url+'/OMS/oms1/fromscratchmodified?screen_ids=' + screen_ids,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            timeout: 5000,
            jsonp: false,
            success: function(response) {
            },
            error: function(x, t, m) {
                if(t==="timeout") {
                    recall();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Data Connection Too Weak');
    }

}
```

The question is that the function is being kept keep on called ??

Comment: You dont increase the `number_0f_times_called`. Its always 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Your variable which stores amount of calls always have a value of `1`. You should add `number_0f_times_called` variable value increasing after recalling Your function when `error` occurs:

```
var number_0f_times_called = 0; // global variable 

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url+'/OMS/oms1/fromscratchmodified?screen_ids=' + screen_ids,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 5000,
    jsonp: false,
    success: function(response) {


    },
    error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            number_0f_times_called = 1;
            recall();
        }
    }
});

function recall()
{
   if(number_0f_times_called<=2)
   {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url+'/OMS/oms1/fromscratchmodified?screen_ids=' + screen_ids,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            timeout: 5000,
            jsonp: false,
            success: function(response) {
            },
            error: function(x, t, m) {
                if(t==="timeout") {
                    number_0f_times_called++;
                    recall();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Data Connection Too Weak');
    }

}
```

Comment: should i keep this check under the recall function also number_0f_times_called++; ??

Comment: I think You should add this line under `recall()` function and set the default value on `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is always less than 2
What you probably want is `number_0f_times_called +=  1`